# Case-When Condition in Code Igniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How to use Case-When Condition in Code Igniter? 
I have to convert this query in Codeigniter format please help.

```
$search = "%$search%";
$sql = "SELECT tickerr_tickets.*, tickerr_users2.name as agent_name, tickerr_ticket_departments.name as department_name, CASE WHEN guest_name != '' THEN guest_name ELSE tickerr_users1.name END AS client_final_name FROM tickerr_tickets INNER JOIN tickerr_ticket_departments ON tickerr_tickets.department=tickerr_ticket_departments.id  LEFT JOIN tickerr_users tickerr_users1 ON tickerr_tickets.userid = tickerr_user1.id LEFT JOIN tickerr_users tickerr_users2 ON tickerr_tickets.agentid = tickerr_users2.id WHERE `status`=1 AND `agentid`!=0 (`tickerr_tickets`.`id` LIKE ? OR `tickerr_tickets`.`date` LIKE ? OR `last_update` LIKE ? OR `subject` LIKE ? OR `content` LIKE ? OR `tickerr_ticket_departments`.`name` LIKE ? OR (CASE WHEN guest_name != '' THEN guest_name ELSE tickerr_users.name END) LIKE ? OR `tickerr_users`.`username` LIKE ?) ORDER BY `$order_by` $order LIMIT $starting,$rows";

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($search, $search, $search, $search, $search, $search, $search, $search));
```

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: the passage `(CASE WHEN guest_name != '' THEN guest_name ELSE tickerr_users.name END)` in your where clause is simply wrong because there is no `tickerr_users` table - your aliases are called `tickerr_users1` and `tickerr_users2`

Answer (score 0):

beside the fact, that your native query is wrong because  there is no `tickerr_users table` - your aliases are called `tickerr_users1` and `tickerr_users2`, 
a proper solution would be the use of the built in query builder

something like the following should work

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('tickerr_tickets.*, tickerr_users2.name as agent_name, tickerr_ticket_departments.name as department_name, CASE WHEN guest_name != \'\' THEN guest_name ELSE tickerr_users1.name END AS client_final_name', false)
    ->from('tickerr_tickets')
    ->join('tickerr_ticket_departments', 'tickerr_tickets.department=tickerr_ticket_departments.id','inner')
    ->join('tickerr_users as tickerr_users1', 'tickerr_tickets.userid = tickerr_user1.id', 'left')
    ->join('tickerr_users as tickerr_users2', 'tickerr_tickets.agentid = tickerr_users2.id', 'left')
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->where('agentid !=', 0)
    ->group_start()
        ->like('tickerr_tickets.id', $search)
        ->or_like('tickerr_tickets.date', $search)
        ->or_like('tickerr_tickets.date', $search)
        ->or_like('tickerr_tickets.last_update', $search)
        ->or_like('tickerr_tickets.subject', $search)
        ->or_like('tickerr_tickets.content', $search)
        ->or_like('tickerr_ticket_departments.name', $search)
        ->or_like('tickerr_users1.username', $search)
        ->or_where('(CASE WHEN guest_name != \'\' THEN guest_name ELSE tickerr_users.name END) LIKE '.$this->db->escape('%'.$search.'%').'', NULL, false)
    ->group_end()
    ->order_by($order_by)
    ->limit($rows, $starting)
    ->get();
```